# Why removing class with jquery is not being done fast?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I use animate.css in most of my websites cause it's freaking awesome but frequently I got stuck with a problem.

Please see this link -> http://quemfazsite.com.br/temp/teste8.php

Code below if you want to inspect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" type="text/css" />


</head>

<body>

<div onclick="$('#xxx').removeClass('flipInX').addClass('flipInX');" style="cursor:pointer;">CLICK TO ANIMATE IMMEDIATLY!</div>

<div onclick="$('#xxx').removeClass('flipInX'); window.setTimeout(function(){$('#xxx').addClass('flipInX')},100);" style="cursor:pointer;">CLICK TO ANIMATE WITH TIMEOUT!</div>

<div id="xxx" style="background:#FF0000; width:500px; height:500px;" class="animated flipInX"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have an element already with the class "flipInX" when page loads. Ok, if you click the first button (top of the page) I simply remove this class and add it again. BUT NO ANIMATION HAPPENS! I use this:

```
$('#xxx').removeClass('flipInX').addClass('flipInX');
```

BUT if I use the second button (code below) the animation happens:

```
$('#xxx').removeClass('flipInX');
window.setTimeout(function(){$('#xxx').addClass('flipInX')},100);
```

Is there some bug with jquery? I mean, it looks like the chaining is not working properfly, if the class had been removed with "removeClass" the effect should have worked when the class gets added back! What is going on and how can I solve it?

EDIT:

The code below does not work too, so dont need to waste your time using delay cause unfortunatelly it wont work :(

```
$('#xxx').removeClass('flipInX').delay(1000).addClass('flipInX');
```

Comment: "Please see this link ->" No. Post a [mcve] in your question so that we can see the issue. I don't like visiting unknown thirds party sites, plus once the problem is fixed, the relevant code problem goes away.

Comment: @j08691 sorry dear friend, I pasted the code so you can see it better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The animation has a delay to execute, in milliseconds.

When you remove the class and re-add it immediately, the animation does not have time to execute. jQuery doesn't "wait" for the animation to execute between "remove" and "add".

The `setTimeout()` is needed to to let you see the animation of the class removal before re-adding the class... That is how you tell jQuery to wait in between.

And `.delay()` works on jQuery animation queue... So between two `animate()`, it will work. It doesn't work between `addClass()` and `removeClass()` that call a CSS animation.

---

**EDIT**

You have no choice to use `setTimeout()` if you want to use CSS animations from the CDN.
Else, you could make your own CSS animation using [`@keyframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)...
But if your concern is about the markup simplification, you can have it in the click handler. So all you need is the class `animated`.

```
$(".animated").on("click",function(){
  $(this).removeClass("flipInX");
  var that=$(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    that.addClass("flipInX");
  },100);
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PKEqmo)

Comment: Hi my friend, using setTimeout will be hard cause I use this removeClass().addClass() in many places in my code and it would break the chaining that jquery allows! Is there someway that I do something like remove().setTimeout(100).addClass() so the rest of the code in the chaiin will only execute after 100ms?

Comment: I edited with something you may like, about simplified markup.

Comment: It was nt me how down voted. My friend, I liked your suggestion, is there someway to abstract or create some prototype that I an use chaining with jquery? Something like this remove().wait(100).addClass() ? Your code works fine but I lose all chaining and it's not beautifull to use inline as most of my code runs.

Comment: I don't know any way to create in chained delay.

Answer (score 0):

delay doesn't work for addClass, first problem, the use of setTimeout() or .queue() is recommended.

maybe **.animate()** is a good method for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I dont like animate, sorry! It's not fast. Do you know someway of using setTimeout with the chaining that jquery allows?